# Pegando indentação com Expressão Regular

Tags: javascript, regex

Gostaria que alguém me ajude a criar um ER que pegue apenas uma marcação e todos as linhas que estejam indentados a frente.

exemplo:

```
aaa
abab aca
marcacao
   aaa
   abab aca
   cc
cc
bb
```

Com o código acima a ER retornaria:

```
marcacao
   aaa
   abab aca
   cc
```

Meu código está escrito em JavaScript então eu uso .match() em minhas ERs.

[editado]

Descrevi melhor meu problema nos comentários abaixo.

Esse é o meu código real:

```
DOCTYPE html
html
    head
        title gulp-gotohead
        style.
            article {border:1px solid}
        style(data-above-the-fold="true").
            body {font-size:100%}
            body{font-size:100%}
            body.main{font-size:100%}
            body, h1{font-size:100%}
            body>h1{font-size:100%}
            header {color:#333}
        script(data-above-the-fold="true").
            var head = Head();
            head();
    body (data-d="true")
        h1 gulp-gotohead
        p
            span regex
```

Essa é a minha marcação:

```
style(data-above-the-fold="true")
```

E esse é o retorno desejado:

```
style(data-above-the-fold="true").
     body {font-size:100%}
     body{font-size:100%}
     body.main{font-size:100%}
     body, h1{font-size:100%}
     body>h1{font-size:100%}
     header {color:#333}
```

O máximo que eu consigo chegar é pegar os códigos da minha marcação para baixo http://regex101.com/r/mZ2xS4/1.

Comment: Como é que está a capturar esse texto? do HTML? pode colocar o HTML para testarmos? Não vou responder sem o HTML para ter a certeza, mas imagino que seja algo assim: __http://regex101.com/r/sH4mZ1/1__

Comment: Será que usar _regex_ não seria um **[problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/)**?

Comment: JavaScript != HTML, @Sergio. Não é necessário HTML para se usar JavaScript e `RegExp`.

Comment: O Bacco tem razão, vou tentar explicar meu problema real.
Estou desenvolvendo um plugin para Gulp que automatiza a tarefa de colocar códigos CSS e JS dentro da tag HEAD de um documento HTML.
Quando o fonte está em HTML puro é fácil criar uma ER para identificar a minha marcação e trocar o código antigo pelo novo. O problema acontece quando o código está escrito em Jade, onde as tag HTML podem ser muito parecidas com marcações CSS e scripts em JS. Estou com dificuldade de encontrar uma ER que pegue apenas a minha marcação ignorando o resto do código fonte do arquivo.

Comment: @sergiopereira, sim verdade, bem sei. Daí a minha pergunta ao Belchior sobre "de onde vem o conteudo/texto"

Comment: @BelchiorOliveira agora que você revelou que está mesmo é querendo criar or consumir uma sintaxe específica, eu concordaria com Bacco e iria evitar RegExp nesse caso. Eu sugeriria [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) e [ANTLR-JavaScript](https://code.google.com/p/antlr-javascript/). Há uma considerável curva de aprendizado com essa ferramenta mas ela existe exatamente para esse propósito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você realmente quiser usar uma expressão regular, acho que a seguinte regex faz o que você quer:

```
^(\s*)style\(data-above-the-fold="true"\)\.\n(\1\s+.*\n)*
```

http://regex101.com/r/mZ2xS4/3

O `^(\s*)` captura a indentação antes do seu marcador inicial. Como esse é a primeira captura da regex, podemos nos referir a ela com `\1`. O `^` serve pra garantir que começamos no início da linha e evita backtracking desnecesário.

O `\1\s+` reconhece uma sequência de espaços maiores que a sequência antes do seu marcador. Tome cuidado para não misturar tabs com espaços.

Finalmente, adicionei uns `\n` aqui e ali, já que `.` não conta como fim de linha.

---

Uma variação a considerar além disso é trocar todos os `\s` por  (espaço), `\t` ou `[ \t]`, dependendo de sua opinião sobre a mistura de tabs com espaços. Isso seriviria para evitar que quebras de linha sejam tratadas como indentação.

Comment: Cara, é isso mesmo.

Comment: Eu não estava conseguindo pensar em algo assim, não tinha bem definido na minha cabeça essa idéia de repita esse subconjunto (\1\s+.*\n)*. Essa parte foi matadora.

Answer (score 1):

Isso funciona.

```
var resultado = seuTexto.match(/^marcacao(\s\s+.+$)+/m )[0];
```

Edit: *Essa resposta foi data antes do OP explicar o problema todo. Daí a simplicidade da RegExp. O problema conforme atualmente descrito acima é bem mais complexo e essa resposta fica aqui só a título de exemplo.*

Comment: Sergiopereira, obrigado pela sua resposta, mais sua ER ainda não me ajuda, eu postei um link com o meu código real, se você puder dar uma olhada, vou ficar bastante agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez até dê pra resolver o seu problema com Regex mas acredito que a restrição de fazer com que as linhas sequintes tenham mais indentação que a primeira deixaria a regex bem complicada. Eu resolveria esse problema escrevendo código na mão mesmo:

Em pseudocódigo

```
marcação = 'style(data-above-the-fold="true")';

function get_line(){
   pega a próxima linha da entrada e retorna dois valores:
   - o número de espaços no início da linha e 
   - uma string com o resto da linha
}

repeat {
    root_indent, root_data = get_line();
} until(root_data == marcação )

styles = [];
loop {
    indent, style = get_line();
    if (indent <= parent_indent ) { break }
    styles.push(style);
}
```

Uma vantagem de resolver assim ao invés de usando uma regex é que a saida do algoritmo é uma lista estruturada ao invés de uma stringzona e o código escrito na mão é mais flexível do que uma regex se você precisar mudar a lógica mais tarde.